# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined outside page.evaluate()

Tags: javascript, node.js, undefined, puppeteer

Consider the following piece of code :

```
let foo = await page.evaluate(
  () => {
    let bar = [...document.querySelectorAll(".foobar")];
    return bar.map( (u) => u.textContent.trim() );
  }
);
foo.forEach( (u) => { console.log(u); });
```

Now consider this variation :

```
let bar = await page.evaluate(
  () => {
    return [...document.querySelectorAll(".foobar")];
  }
);
let foo = bar.map((u) => u.textContent.trim());
bar.forEach( (u) => { console.log(u); } );
```

I would expect both to log the same results, but actually while the former runs fine, the latter throws

> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Can somebody explain why I can't take the `map()` out of `page.evaluate()` ?

FWIW, `page` is a `puppeteer` `NewPage()`.

Comment: Second question: Can you really pass DOM elements from the page's context to the testing code's context in Puppeteer? (Sorry, don't know the tool well.) That's one big difference in the two code blocks, the first just passes strings between contexts.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It was a typo indeed, edited.

Comment: Good deal. Always best to use copy-and-paste. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function passed to `page.evaluate` gets serialised and sent over a network to the browser where it is then executed. This means the return value also has to be sent over the network, and therefore [serialisable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Serialization). A list of elements is not serialisable.

As [mentioned in the documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args), if the return value of the function is not serialisable, then undefined is returned instead.

Comment: Ah, [my suspicion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55665954/cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined-outside-page-evaluate#comment98018639_55665954) was correct then. It can really only exchange things that can be `JSON.stringify`d?

Comment: As mentioned in the linked docs, anything that can be serialised as JSON, as well as "some additional values that are not serializable by JSON: -0, NaN, Infinity, -Infinity, and bigint literals."

Comment: Huh, I searched "Serializable" in the docs and only ever got links to `JSON.stringify` on MDN. Still, I trust it's there somewhere. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it's on `evaluate`: *"DevTools Protocol also supports transferring some additional values that are not serializable by JSON: -0, NaN, Infinity, -Infinity, and bigint literals."* Not especially clear, but...

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou Is there some rule where we have to use US English spelling of serialise? If not, I don't appreciate the edit.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly the "sent over a network" part (I assume it is not to be interpreted literally).  Can you point out some documentation ?

Comment: @CameronMartin Sorry, English not being my native language it didn't even occur to me there might have been a different UK/US convention.  All (and [not only](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)) the docs seemed to use a 'z', so I thought it was a typo (actually I assumed it was a computing neologism).

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou As mentioned at the start of the [puppeteer README](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer#readme), it uses the [devtools protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) for communicating with the browser. This is [based on JSONRPC](https://github.com/aslushnikov/getting-started-with-cdp/blob/master/README.md#protocol-fundamentals). Whether messages are actually sent over a network is actually inconsequential, although this will normally be the case - the key part is that all messages have to be serialisable when using this protocol.

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou Additionally, if you're wondering what it means to serialise a function, [the `toString` method is simply called on it](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/a8ffdad76e3df1f209f92a69e4df25a6a10855f2/lib/ExecutionContext.js#L87), which returns the source code of the function.